# More than one baggage is allowed or more than one baggages are allowed?

Tags: countability

which is correct?

More than one  baggage is allowed

or

More than one baggages are allowed

Comment: ThanksColleenC  for pointing out the mistake with the use of  baggages.

Comment: My doubt is  whether " one car  Is allowed " , "or more than one cars  are  allowed "   is the right usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the entry for **baggage** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/baggage), you will see the letter U next to the word: that means it is uncountable, like sugar or leather.

You can't have one baggage, or more than one baggage, and you certainly can't have a plural **baggages**. You just have baggage.

The sentence can be fixed in one of two ways. You can replace baggage by [bag](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bag), which is countable (note the C in brackets next to the [dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bag)):

> More than one bag is allowed

Alternatively, you can talk about a [piece](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/piece) of baggage, which is also countable:

> More than one piece of baggage is allowed.

Comment: One other way to make a word countable is to use it at the front of a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). It doesn’t work so well with _baggage_ (at least, not in American English, I don’t think), but I think it could work with _luggage_ instead of _baggage_: _More than one **luggage item** is allowed._

Comment: I feel that OP intended to ask whether more than one IS allowed, or more than one ARE allowed.